# Php version setting on hostgator

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, shared-hosting

I would like to deploy my Laravel 3 project on Hostgator shared hosting.
The minimum php needed for Laravel 3 is php56. The default php in Hostgator is php54 which is lower than the needed version.

I followed this [instruction](http://www.drewkeller.com/blog/selecting-php-command-line-version-hostgator-shared-host) to locate php56 in HG then I found it.
Then I edited the ~/.bashrc.

```
    [ -z "$PS1" ] && return
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions

alias php='/opt/php56/bin/php'
alias composer='/usr/bin/php-cli ~/bin/composer/composer.phar'
export DRUSH_PHP='/opt/php56/bin/php'
```

Now when I check the php --version it clearly says it's `PHP 5.6.30`

> PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Mar 27 2017 11:42:52) Copyright (c) 1997-2016
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend
>   Technologies
>       with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v6.0.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by
>   ionCube Ltd.

However when I tried to run composer install on the project root it said that the installed php version is 5.4.45 hence does not satisfy the requirements.

> - symfony/yaml v3.3.4 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 35
>
>   - nikic/php-parser v3.0.6 requires php >=5.5 -> your PHP version (5.4.45) does not satisfy that requirement.
>   - psy/psysh v0.8.9 requires nikic/php-parser ~1.3|~2.0|~3.0 -> satisfiable by nikic/php-parser[v3.0.6].
>   - Installation request for psy/psysh v0.8.9 -> satisfiable by psy/psysh[v0.8.9].

How can I correctly configure the system in shared hosting to use the correct PHP version ?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Hostgator](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/compatible-technologies), Laravel is compatible with their shared platforms. Several posts related to the installation of Laravel on HG are available. Probably the most helpful is [this one](https://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-how-to-install-laravel-on-a-hostgator-shared-server).

In looking over your question, it appears that you have neglected to add the php handler to the .htaccess file in the application root directory. I suggest you start there.

Please be aware that you can contact HG Live Support and request assistance with the installation. They may be willing to perform the installation for you; however, they will not support any direct development work you have.